# Polynomial kernel feature space?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

Given a kernel with the form:

[image]
and x,z in R^n, how do you prove that the feature space is (n+d) choose n?
Note: sorry the rest of the question is not in Latex as I do not yet have enough reputation to post more than 1 link.

Comment: Stackexchange compiles Tex in your questions/answers/comments, so you can just do it yourself, no links needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/ml/ml10/sol3.pdf) link at the first item to provide detail solution.

In short, polynomial kernel $K(x,z) = (x \cdot z + 1)^d$ is represented in terms of monomials. The problem of determining the number of monomials of degree *exactly* $d$ in $N$ input variables is the same as the problem of finding the number of combination to sum of $N$ elements less than $d$. The number of such a problem is $N + d \choose d$.